# java : return inherited child class type

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a CRUD system using Hibernate. 
I want to build an interface for all my DB objects :

```
public abstract class ADBElem { }
```

here is an example of a DB object method (read) :

```
public static PrdProduct read(Integer id) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    PrdProduct product = null;
    product = (PrdProduct) session.get(PrdProduct.class, id);
    session.close();
    return product;
}
```

The return type depends of the inherited class, how do i put this method in my abstract class ?

What i found so far :

```
public abstract class ADBElem<T> {
    public static T read(Integer id) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    T item = null;
    item = (T) session.get(T.class, id);
    session.close();
    return item;
 }

public class PrdProduct extends ADBElem<PrdProduct> {}
```

but its not working, i got this error : cannot make static reference to non static type t

Comment: I think you are trying to create a generic dao.

Comment: I'm not familliar with the ORM, but it might be it

Comment: Where's the read method in the abstract class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With static (utility) methods, you can type *just the method*. However, there is no way to get the `Class` of a generic type, so you must pass in a `Class` object too.

Here's how you can code it to work as a static method (regardless of whether the class is typed):

```
public static <T> T read(Integer id, Class<T> clazz) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    T object = (T) session.get(clazz, id);
    session.close();
    return object;
}
```

When used, java will *infer* the type, so you can simply code (without casts) the call like this:

```
PrdProduct product = MyClass.read(1, PrdProduct.class);
```

Comment: PrdProduct.read(1, PrdProduct.class); is quite redundant, what do you think ?

Comment: @overlox No. It appears to be redundant, but because your method requires an *instance* of the class, you *must* pass it in - there is no way around it. It's just the way java is.

Comment: @overlox the method will retrieve an instance of the class passed in (based on the ID passed in) but you will get a `ClassCastException` when you try to assign the object returned from this method to your local variable.

Answer (score 2):

In the abstract class you must add the method signature with a return type that is a superclass of `PrdProduct` or a interface implemented by it. Then the concrete methods must return that same abstract type regardless of the concrete type.

```
public abstract class ADBElem { 
    public static SomeSuperCLass read(Integer id);
}

public class PrdProduct extends SomeSuperCLass {
    public static SomeSuperCLassOrInterface read(Integer id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        PrdProduct product = null;
        product = (PrdProduct) session.get(PrdProduct.class, id);
        session.close();
        // return product which is also a `SomeSuperClass`
        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but the idea was to keep PrdProduct empty, and put all the code in the abstract class, i think i found how to do it using generics

Comment: @overlox Please show us how you did it with generics. I didn't know that was even possible.